# Android HERE maps on map settled listener

Tags: android, here-api

I need to run a reverse geoCode request when the map has "settled". The closest thing I could find was the TransformListener:

```
mMap.addTransformListener(new Map.OnTransformListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapTransformStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMapTransformEnd(MapState mapState) {


        }
    });
```

The problem is that onMapTransformEnd fires multiple times while the map is being dragged. Also tried adding a gesture listener to the mapview, but this doesn't seem to callback at the proper time either, as onPanEnd() isn't called until the user touches again.

```
mMapView.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(new MapGesture.OnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPanStart() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPanEnd() {

        }
```

Is there a callback for when the map has finished moving and is settled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a delay since the api didn't offer a settled listener:

```
mMap.addTransformListener(new Map.OnTransformListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapTransformStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onMapTransformEnd(MapState mapState) {
                // This works but is not optimal. I'd rather not wait a whole second before sending
                // the geocoder request, but a half second is too fast to send only one request.
                if(!mRunning) {
                    mRunning = true;
                    mSettledHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updatePickupViewOnMapSettled();
                            mRunning = false;
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Very quick answer, but if it is dragging specifically you are worried about, why not add your own hysteresis to `OnTransformListener`. I.e. a small wait time between `onMapTransformEnd` callback and when you execute your code. It would be canceled upon another `onMapTransformStart` callback.

The general callback for when the `Map` has settled is in fact `onMapTransformEnd`.

Comment: That would be my backup plan should there turn out to be no support for map settled in the API.